# How to access s3a:// files from Apache Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Hadoop 2.6 doesn't support s3a out of the box, so I've tried a series of solutions and fixes, including:

deploy with hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk => cannot read environment variable for credentials
add hadoop-aws into maven => various transitive dependency conflicts

Has anyone successfully make both work?

Comment: Which version of Apache Spark are you using?

Comment: Related: [SPARK-7442](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7442)

Comment: 1.3.1_ scala 2.10.4_hadoop 2.6. I just found that s3:// and s3n:// also doesn't work out of the box (they only works on hadoop 2.4)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Having experienced first hand the difference between s3a and s3n - 7.9GB of data transferred on s3a was around ~7 minutes while 7.9GB of data on s3n took 73 minutes [us-east-1 to us-west-1 unfortunately in both cases; Redshift and Lambda being us-east-1 at this time] this is a very important piece of the stack to get correct and it's worth the frustration.

Here are the key parts, as of December 2015:

1. Your Spark cluster will need a Hadoop version 2.x or greater. If you use the Spark EC2 setup scripts and maybe missed it, the switch for using something other than 1.0 is to specify `--hadoop-major-version 2` (which uses CDH 4.2 as of this writing).
2. You'll need to include what may at first seem to be an out of date AWS SDK library (built in 2014 as version 1.7.4) for versions of Hadoop as late as 2.7.1 (stable): aws-java-sdk 1.7.4. As far as I can tell using this along with the specific AWS SDK JARs for 1.10.8 hasn't broken anything.
3. You'll also need the hadoop-aws 2.7.1 JAR on the classpath. This JAR contains the class `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`.
4. In `spark.properties` you probably want some settings that look like this:

   `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=ACCESSKEY   spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=SECRETKEY`
5. If you are using hadoop 2.7 version with spark then the aws client uses V2 as default auth signature. And all the new aws region support only V4 protocol. To use V4 pass these conf in spark-submit and also endpoint (format - `s3.<region>.amazonaws.com`) must be specified.

`--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true`

`--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true`

I've detailed this list in more detail on a [post I wrote](http://deploymentzone.com/2015/12/20/s3a-on-spark-on-aws-ec2/) as I worked my way through this process. In addition I've covered all the exception cases I hit along the way and what I believe to be the cause of each and how to fix them.

Comment: This was helpful for me.  The only dependency I ended up adding was "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.0.0-alpha2" at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.0.0-alpha2

Comment: Having `hadoop-aws 2.7.1` (or higher) JAR on the classpath solved the issue for me, but when running on Amazon EMR I didnt need this, so I made it a provided dependency, my sbt looks like 

`"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.8.1" % Provided`

Comment: Sorry haven't seen the big update as it's a very old question, marked as accepted despite not having verified myself

Answer (score 25):

I'm writing this answer to access files with **S3A** from **Spark 2.0.1** on **Hadoop 2.7.3**

Copy the AWS jars(`hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` and `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`) which shipped with Hadoop by default

- **Hint:** If the jar locations are unsure? Running find command as a privileged user can be helpful; commands can be

  ```
    find / -name hadoop-aws*.jar
    find / -name aws-java-sdk*.jar
  ```

into **spark classpath** which holds all spark jars

- **Hint:** We can not directly point the location(It must be in property file) as I want to make an answer generic for distributions and Linux flavors. **spark classpath** can be identified by find command below

  ```
    find / -name spark-core*.jar
  ```

### in `spark-defaults.conf`

**Hint:** (Mostly it will be placed in `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`)

```
#make sure jars are added to CLASSPATH
spark.yarn.jars=file://{spark/home/dir}/jars/*.jar,file://{hadoop/install/dir}/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar


spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem  
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key={s3a.access.key} 
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key={s3a.secret.key} 
#you can set above 3 properties in hadoop level `core-site.xml` as well by removing spark prefix.
```

in spark submit include jars(`aws-java-sdk` and `hadoop-aws`) in `--driver-class-path` if needed.

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
  --driver-class-path {spark/jars/home/dir}/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar \
  --driver-class-path {spark/jars/home/dir}/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar \
  other options
```

> **Note:**
>
> Make sure the Linux user with reading privileges, before running the
> `find` command to prevent error *Permission denied*

Comment: you can get these by
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.ja
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar

Comment: Zeppelin Spark version 2.2, I am able to connect to S3 central region which support V4 signature only.  Set below properties along with jars (artifacts) suggested by mrsrinivas.                   
``` System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", accessKey)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey) ```

Answer (score 13):

I got it working using the Spark 1.4.1 prebuilt binary with hadoop 2.6
Make sure you set both `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` pointing to the two jars (hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk)
If you run on a cluster, make sure your executors have access to the jar files on the cluster.

Comment: same problem: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 27, 10.122.113.63): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n

Comment: If it is default in nature for all s3, add the two variables in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf. Ref http://deploymentzone.com/2015/12/20/s3a-on-spark-on-aws-ec2/ is a good source.

Answer (score 8):

We're using spark 1.6.1 with Mesos and we were getting lots of issues writing to S3 from spark. I give credit to cfeduke for the answer. The slight change I made was adding maven coordinates to the spark.jar config in the spark-defaults.conf file. I tried with hadoop-aws:2.7.2 but was still getting lots of errors so we went back to 2.7.1. Below are the changes in spark-defaults.conf that are working for us:

```
spark.jars.packages             net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.0,com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key  <MY ACCESS KEY>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key  <MY SECRET KEY>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload true
```

Thank you cfeduke for taking the time to write up your post. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the details as of October 2016, as presented at Spark Summit EU: [Apache Spark and Object Stores](http://www.slideshare.net/steve_l/apache-spark-and-object-stores).

Key points

- The direct output committer is gone from Spark 2.0 due to risk/experience of data corruption.
- There are some settings on the FileOutputCommitter to reduce renames, but not eliminate them
- I'm working with some colleagues to do an O(1) committer, relying on Apache Dynamo to give us that consistency we need.
- To use S3a, get your classpath right.
- And be on Hadoop 2.7.z; 2.6.x had some problems which were addressed by then [HADOOP-11571](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11571).
- There's a PR under SPARK-7481 to pull everything into a spark distro you build yourself. Otherwise, ask whoever supplies to the binaries to do the work.
- Hadoop 2.8 is going to add major perf improvements [HADOOP-11694](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11694).

Product placement: the read-performance side of HADOOP-11694 is included in HDP2.5; The [Spark and S3 documentation](https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-spark/) there might be of interest —especially the tuning options.

Answer (score 3):

as you said, hadoop 2.6 doesn't support s3a, and latest spark release 1.6.1 doesn't support hadoop 2.7, but spark 2.0 is definitely no problem with hadoop 2.7 and s3a.

for spark 1.6.x, we made some dirty hack, with the s3 driver from EMR... you can take a look this doc: https://github.com/zalando/spark-appliance#emrfs-support

if you still want to try to use s3a in spark 1.6.x, refer to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487407/5630352

Answer (score 2):

Using Spark 1.4.1 pre-built with Hadoop 2.6, I am able to get s3a:// to work when deploying to a Spark Standalone cluster by adding the hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk jar files from the Hadoop 2.7.1 distro (found under $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib of Hadoop 2.7.1) to my SPARK_CLASSPATH environment variable in my $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh file.

Comment: Really? Let me try your solutions again on 1.4.1, I wasn't commited to s3a as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7442 is still marked as 'unresolved'

Comment: Ive tried, seems like something else is missing, I keep getting this error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 47, 10.122.113.63): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n

Comment: Oh, and here is deprecation conflict in your solution: 
          |SPARK_CLASSPATH was detected (set to '$value').
          |This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.
          |
          |Please instead use:
          | - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
          | - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath

Comment: Specifically, even as late as Dec 31 2015 you need to use an AWS SDK library compiled in 2014:  aws-java-sdk 1.7.4; this answer above is the most accurate answer on this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the S3A dependencies to the classpath using `spark-defaults.conf`.

Example:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath     /usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath     /usr/local/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /usr/local/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

Or just:

```
spark.jars     /usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar,/usr/local/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

Just make sure to match your AWS SDK version to the version of Hadoop. For more information about this, look at this answer: [Unable to access S3 data using Spark 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48752069/4245294)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for pyspark (possibly with proxy):

```
def _configure_s3_protocol(spark, proxy=props["proxy"]["host"], port=props["proxy"]["port"], endpoint=props["s3endpoint"]["irland"]):
    """
    Configure access to the protocol s3
    https://sparkour.urizone.net/recipes/using-s3/
    AWS Regions and Endpoints
    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html
    """
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",  os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"))
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.proxy.host", proxy)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.proxy.port", port)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", endpoint)
    return spark
```

Comment: what is the `props` variable?

Comment: a normal python dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **scala** version that works fine with **Spark 3.2.1** (pre-built) with **Hadoop 3.3.1**, accessing a S3 bucket from a non AWS machine [typically a local setup on a developer machine]

**sbt**

```scala
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.1" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.2.1" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.1" % "provided",
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.3.1",
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.3.1" % "provided"
  )
```

**spark program**

```scala
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Process parquet file")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", true)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", ENDPOINT)
    .config(
      "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl",
      "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
    )
    // The enable V4 does not seem necessary for the eu-west-3 region
    // see @stevel comment below 
    // .config("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", true)
    // .config(
    //  "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions",
    //  "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true"
    // )
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "4")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://[BUCKET NAME]/.../???.parquet")
  df.show()
```

*note*: region is in the form `s3.[REGION].amazonaws.com` e.g. `s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com`

**s3 configuration**

To make the bucket available from outside of AWS, add a Bucket Policy of the form:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT ID]:user/[IAM USERNAME]"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Delete*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET NAME]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The supplied ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY to the spark configuration must be those of the IAM user configured on the bucket

Comment: looks good but you don't need
- the fs.s3a.impl declaration. this is a superstition only found in stack overflow examples
- the com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true sysprop. that was only for older aws sdk versions.

Comment: @stevel Thanks - will edit the answer then

Answer (score -3):

I am using spark version 2.3, and when I save a dataset using spark like:

```
dataset.write().format("hive").option("fileFormat", "orc").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .option("path", "s3://reporting/default/temp/job_application")
    .saveAsTable("job_application");
```

It works perfectly and saves my data into s3.

Comment: IF you are using "s3" then you are using Amazon EMR, so unrelated. And It worked for you in the absence of failures and observable inconsistencies. You cannot rely on that working in production, hence the S3A committers of Hadoop 3.1