# spark aws S3a ARN (Amazon Resource Name) IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm using spark 2.3.0 and Hadoop 2.7 ( but i can upgrade if necessary)

I want acces S3 file with an ARN (Amazon Resource Name) IAM Role
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

I already took a look to this [How to access s3a:// files from Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385981/how-to-access-s3a-files-from-apache-spark) but there is no question about IAM acces

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession sc = new SparkSession.Builder()
                .appName("test")
                .config("spark.master", "local[*]") //for example
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "****")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "****")
                // .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.arn_role","arn:aws:iam::***:role/******"")
                .getOrCreate();

        sc.read().format("csv").load("s3a://toto/****.csv").printSchema();

    }
}
```

I didn't find any option or configuration

I'm also looking for a solution with args on the spark submit ,but not inside a configuration files ( this need to by dynamic )

do you have any idea ?

Comment: If you're already giving it access keys, what benefits do IAMs give you? Aren't roles tied to those keys already?

Comment: No those are not the keys of the role , they are private keys who can take the role .

Like when you do in CLI : aws s3 ls --profile myProfile

( who resolve the profile role_arn inside .aws/config file )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit support for IAM assumed roles is a very new feature in the S3A code [HADOOP-15141](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15141), and still not completely stable [HADOOP-15583](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15583), so you won't gain anything by upgrading.

What could is the session credential support of 2.8 [HADOOP-12537](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12537)

Here you'd need to somehow get the temporary credentials for your IAM role (maybe AWS CLI? If not, a little bit of the AWS SDK lets you do this. Imagine a mix of [this code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/ITestS3ATemporaryCredentials.java#L80) and [this](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/auth/AssumedRoleCredentialProvider.java#L111).

The assumeRole code gives you the session credential set of (access key, secret key, session token), which you then need to set in the spark context, *and switch the credential provider to the temporary provider*, as covered [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Changing_Authentication_Providers).

you should then be able to work through spark in that IAM Role until the session expires (which has now been extended to last a few hours; until March 2018 they only lasted a few minutes).

The full IAM role support in Hadoop 3.1+ lets you declare the IAM role and any extra policy, and have the connector automatically log you in then refresh the session tokens regularly. You won't have that, so your spark job can't last longer than the lifespan of the credentials you obtained at launch time.

Comment: Update: [HADOOP-14556](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14556) will do exactly what you want: automatically assume a role client side, get credentials and pass them with your job. Your long-lived secrets will never go into the cluster. It also restricts the assumed role to the specific bucket/s3guard DDB table the specific s3a:// URL is bonded to.

Answer (score 1):

If you run spark on ec2 and want to use IAM role then you don't need to change your code, just create a role in IAM console and assign to your ec2. Everything that run on that instance inherit the role privileges.

If you run on EMR, create role and specify the role arn in lambda script that calls the EMR cluster API, access the role arn via lambda environment parameter.

Comment: No it's not running on EC2 , its for local use , but thanks for the advices

Comment: In that case, a role is tied to a group, the a user belong to that group will inherited group's privileges, you don't need arn of a role.

Comment: I have updated the question. I trully need to pass the ARN , without I don't have the rights , thanks