# Spark uses s3a: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, ceph

I'm doing something about the combination of spark_with_hadoop2.7 (2.4.3), hadoop (3.2.0) and Ceph luminous. When I tried to use spark to access ceph (for example, start `spark-sql` on shell), exception like below shows:

```
 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.getAWSAccessKeys(S3AUtils.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.<init>(SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.createAWSCredentialProviderSet(S3AUtils.java:600)
```

For `NoSuchMethodError`, it's most likely because the compiled class version is different from running class version according to [how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror).

To access `Ceph`, aws related jars `aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar` and `hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar` under `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib`
are actually used. I did operations below:

1, Copy those two jars to `$SPARK_HOME/jars`
2, Modify `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` to add statements below:

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*`

By doing steps above, I can start hdfs to access ceph, for example, I can use `hdfs dfs -ls` to list folders under ceph bucket. It proves that the aws related jars works fine.(Just as per my understanding).

But why exceptions about aws s3a throw when I invoke spark?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access s3a:// files from Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385981/how-to-access-s3a-files-from-apache-spark)

Comment: @Yogesh I checked that link before, it doesn't solve my problem. According to my current understanding, the spark I used is spark2.4.3_with_built-in_hadoop2.7, it's should be the problem. I need to use spark2.4.3_without_hadoop version I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the hadoop-* JARs need to be 100% matching on versions, else you get to see stack traces like this.

For more information please reread

Comment: How to find whether jars are matching or not without trial and error method?

Comment: they all have the same suffix, like -2.8.4 or -3.1.2

Comment: hi, I have the same error so I tried, but something is not clear: should I copy all of hadoop-*-3.2.1.jar to the spark jars folder? (my Hadoop version is 3.2.1)
(I have all original file in the spark jars folder with version 2.7.3)

Comment: All the hadoop-* JARs need to be 100% matching on versions, else you get to see stack traces like this.

Comment: `all the hadoop-* JARs need to be 100% matching on versions` is the key sentence with resolved my hours of debugging issues. Thanks