# Identifying Correct JAR Versions for S3 Integration with PySpark 3.5

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am attempting to set up a PySpark environment to read data from S3 using PySpark 3.5 in a Conda environment (Python 3.12). However, I am facing difficulties in identifying the correct versions of the **aws-java-sdk** and **hadoop-aws** JARs to use (needed for reading data from S3 directly). Here are the steps I have followed and the issues I have encountered:

```bash
conda create --name spark_env
conda activate spark_env
pip install pyspark
```

Then in my Jupyter notebook (That is using the previously created environment), I'm creating the SparkSession:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Read from S3") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "AWS_ACCESS_KEY") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "AWS_SECRET_KEY") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .getOrCreate()

s3_path = "s3a://bucket/file.json"
df = spark.read.json(s3_path)
df.show()
```

What gaves me the following exception:

*"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found"*

That's why I have tried to download different versions of

- [hadoop-aws](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws)
- [aws-java-sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk)

But after adding these jars to the /jars path that Pyspark is using (I have also tried specifying manually the path to these jars), I keep getting exceptions like:

"*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.impl.prefetch.PrefetchingStatistics"*

or

"""
*Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.json.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10001) (YYY executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.impl.IOStatisticsBinding.invokeTrackingDuration(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/statistics/DurationTracker;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/functional/CallableRaisingIOE;)Ljava/lang/Object;*

or

*"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException"*

**Can someone guide me on how to identify the correct versions of the aws-java-sdk and hadoop-aws JARs to use with PySpark 3.5 for S3 integration, or provide a reliable source where this information is available? Additionally, if there's a different or more recommended approach to reading data from S3 using PySpark 3.5, I'm open to suggestions.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: s3a paths need to be handled differently it seems. Take a look at this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385981/how-to-access-s3a-files-from-apache-spark

Comment: Don't add the JARs manually. Use the `spark.jars.packages` config, e.g. `.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.6')`

Answer (score -1):

#### Receipe:

Scala version - -> 2.13

Spark version - -> 3.5.0

hadoop-client version - -> 3.3.4

hadoop-aws - -> 3.3.4

Delta format support too

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.3.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.1.0 pyspark-shell'
conf = SparkConf()
conf = conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
conf = conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
conf = conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
conf = conf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
conf = conf.setAppName('pyspark_aws_delta').setMaster('local[*]')
conf = conf.set('spark.delta.logStore.class','org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore')

#DEFINE SPARK CONTEXT
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
hadoopConf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")

hadoopConf.set('fs.s3.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')

#define buckets
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.bucket.{}.access.key'.format(BUCKET_NAME), ACCESS_KEY)
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.bucket.{}.secret.key'.format(BUCKET_NAME), SECRET)

# DEFINE SPARK SESSION
spark=SparkSession(sc)
```

references:

https://medium.com/@ramachandrankrish/integrating-org-apache-hadoop-fs-s3a-s3afilesystem-to-access-the-aws-s3-bucket-via-spark-java-3744ffadb60d

Comment: 1. cut the fs.s3a.impl bit, it is a superstition you've picked up from reading other stack overflow examples rather than the s3a docs. thanks. 
2. and those extra java options to enable v4 are also superflous as s3afs v4 signs automatically.