Error reading from S3 using spark-connect on AWS EMR
Im trying to use the new spark-connect functionality in AWS EMR. I'm using AWS EMR version 7.1.0 with these software installed in the cluster:

Spark 3.5.0
Hive 3.1.3
Hadoop 3.3.6

I start running the spark session with this command:

pyspark --remote "<sc://ip_address_of_master_node>"

The cluster is accesible and the spark session seems to be created correctly without errors. Before the creation of spark session, I had to install with pip these libraries:

grpcio_status
pandas
pyarrow
google-api-python-client
grpcio

When I try to read a single parquet file from S3 i'm having the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/dataframe.py", line 126, in __repr__ return "DataFrame[%s]" % (", ".join("%s: %s" % c for c in self.dtypes)) File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/dataframe.py", line 228, in dtypes return [(str(f.name), f.dataType.simpleString()) for f in self.schema.fields] File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/dataframe.py", line 1673, in schema return self._session.client.schema(query) File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py", line 954, in schema schema = self._analyze(method="schema", plan=plan).schema File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py", line 1143, in _analyze self._handle_error(error) File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py", line 1502, in _handle_error self._handle_rpc_error(error) File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py", line 1538, in _handle_rpc_error raise convert_exception(info, status.message) from None pyspark.errors.exceptions.connect.SparkConnectGrpcException: (org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException) No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
Trying to read a local file works well. In EMR s3 connection works by default.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237544/identifying-correct-jar-versions-for-s3-integration-with-pyspark-3-5
You need to add hadoop-aws jars to access s3 from the server. This comment could be useful.
Don't add the JARs manually. Use the spark.jars.packages config, e.g. .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.6') or using --packages on cli.

Now works but with a strangew situatioin. I run this on emr in a bootstrap file: sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.6. This gives me the same error, but if I restart spark-connect after the cluster is running it works well when reading from S3.

use s3a: as the scheme in your URLs. "s3:" is an EMR closed source client
